# Unable to add WCF test in VS2010 test project after installing WCF load test utility

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I have installed "New release (November 2010): WCF Load Test Version 3.0 (Beta) for Visual Studio 2010". After Installing I am expecting to add a WCF test. But on adding new test there is no WCF test option coming. Any idea what I am missing here.

I am following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/12/03/generating-load-tests-for-wcf-services-with-the-wcf-load-test-tool.aspx) guide

Answer (score 0):

Load testing is not supported for VS2010 premium edition. So it wont be visible. Only support for VS2010 ultimate edition